# Google Credentials api with phone number verification

Tags: android, google-api, google-authentication

I am working on authentication procedure and the best that I found is [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/effective-phone-number-verification.html) link. This matches to my app needs perfectaly.

But problem that I am facing is that , after doing described steps, I get a phone number picker dialog shown ad hidden and I get reply in onActivityResult callback as a canceld result and with empty data.

I do not know why that dialog closes it self not letting the user to choose the phone number and it returned it self in the OnActivityResult with canceled result code.

Please help me , I am stuck in it and I have no clue to go in that direction with.

Comment: can you ensure me your region

Comment: asia . .........

Answer (score 0):

I think its the problem of SIM. Some sim card allow this and some not. I will suggest you to do testing on real device. And change your sim card to ensure it must not be the carrier problem.

I have the same issue and then I changed SIM card and that codes start working for me. And that was really amazing to notice that it was not working from all sim cards. I am from India. Hope so it will be helpful for any Asian developer.

Comment: let me test on different sim cards,

Comment: thanks. I thought it might be problem of something that I am missing. But beside this, how the google itself picks up almost every phone number

Comment: that must be from Smart lock . Use credentials API. that is much better approach

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same issue with this.
On some phone(even if it is brand new phone), phone number dialog is appeared and dismissed quickly. 
And then credential id is returning null value.

onActivityResult

```
val credential: Credential? = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
var phoneNumber = credential?.id
if (phoneNumber == null) {
    val tMgr = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    phoneNumber = tMgr.line1Number
}
```

I try to find a reason but failed. Instead, I use telephonyManager in this exceptional case. This is still not a good solution because user should see abnormal behavior and also should agree with phone permission. I also think this is related with SIM card.